# Questions regarding Spring boot and JPA

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I was working on a project using Spring boot, Spring MVC, and Hibernate. I encountered this problem which had already taken me 2 days.

My project was an imitation of twitter. When I started to work on the project, I used the JPA to get the Hibernate Session. Here is the code in my BaseDaoImpl class:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

public Session getSession(){

return entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class);

}
```

In my Service class, I used the @Transactional annotation:

```
@Service("userServ")
@Transactional(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly=false,rollbackFor={Exception.class, RuntimeException.class})
public class UserServImpl implements IUserServ {}
```

And finally, an overview of my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"edu.miis.Entities"})
@ComponentScan({"edu.miis.Controllers","edu.miis.Service","edu.miis.Dao"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
public class FinalProjectSpringbootHibernateDruidApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(FinalProjectSpringbootHibernateDruidApplication.class, args);
    }



}
```

When I was using this setting, everything seemed fine - until I was able to move up to a the extent where I started to add "post" function. I could add posts and comments into the database. However, I could not do this a lot of times. Every time I added up to 4 posts, the program ceased to run - no exceptions, no errors - the page just got stuck there.

I looked up online, realizing that the problem was probably due to the entityManagerFactory. I was told that `entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager().unwrap(Session.class)`opens new Hibernate sessions, instead of the traditional `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` that returns an existing session.

So I started to work on it. I changed my Dao configuration into this:

```
@Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
public Session getSession(){

        Session session = entityManagerFactory.unwrap(SessionFactory.class).getCurrentSession();

        return session;
    }
```

My idea was to use the autowired EntityManagerFactory to return a Hibernate SessionFactory so that the getCurrentSession method can be then used.

But then I got problem:

Since I configured to this setting, any operation that involves input from controller to the service-dao-database invokes an exception: `No Transaction Is In Progress`

But the weird thing is: although the system broke due to no visible transaction in progress, Hibernate still generates new SQL statements, and data still get synchronized into the database.

Can anybody help me over how to get this issue resolved?

Sincerely thanks!

Comment: I ran a few tests. Here is what I did : I deleted the @Transactional annotation, and switched back to entityManager.unwrap. You know what? Without the annotation, the transaction still gets committed. I think it is now very clear that the problem is that I didn't use the spring Transaction manager to manage hibernate session at all.

Comment: But still no progress

Comment: Don't use the `Session` just use the `Entitymanager`. Trying to use plain hibernate makes things overly complex and doesn't add anything (generally with the current state of JPA). Just use the JPA API instead and remove your hacks.

Comment: Could you be more specific? I don't exactly know how to use JPA api...

Comment: You can google for spring boot jpa tutorial. baeldung has a good tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @M. Deinum's suggestion, I finally had this issue resolved.

```
The reason why the @Transactional annotation didn't work in my code in the first place, was because in my original code, I used plain Hibernate features - Session, SessionFactory, getCurrentSession() etc. 

In order for these features to work, I need to specifically configure the transaction manager into a Hibernate Transaction Manager (under default setting, Spring boot autowires a JPA transaction manager).

But the problem is: most of methods that were used to support Hibernate features are now deprecated. Now, the JPA method is the mainstream.

Use EntityManager instead of Session/
Use EntityManager.persist instead of Session.save
Use EntityManager.merge instead of Session.update
Use EntityManager.remove instead of Session.remove.


That's all.

Thanks!
```